# SQL select a specific value from a table, but not when one element occurs in this table

Tags: mysql, sql

I've a question about a specific query i've to perform, but I'm not quite sure how to. So here's my problem.

In the table below, we see guys working in one or more departments; I want to get the workerID of everyone which is at least one time in this table, but has no entry for the department 10.

```
-------------------------
department |workerID |hours
-------------------------
10         |3       |4
10         |8       |5
20         |1       |4
20         |3       |8
20         |4       |6
20         |8       |3
30         |1       |4
30         |3       |3
30         |8       |5
40         |3       |8
40         |7       |8
40         |8       |8
```

It would be very nice if you could help me with this problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Department
    ,WorkerID
FROM tblSample
WHERE Department <> 10
    AND WorkerID IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

if you self join the table to exclude those workers that have a department id = 10 then get the distinct list of workers.

```
select distinct a.workerID 
from table1 a
left outer join table1 b on a.workerid = b.workerid and b.department = 10
where b.workerid is null
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from table
where workerID not in 
  (select workerID 
    from table
    where departmentID = 10)
```